# How to use command line arguments in a referenced library?

Tags: java, dependencies

Given the following structure in my Java program:

- XBase (library)
- XStageRename *references XBase* (executable)
- XStageConvert *references XBase* (executable)

The program itself consists thus of XStageRename and XStageConvert, I pass some common arguments as command line arguments and some specific arguments.

Is there a way to inject the common arguments (which are known beforehand) into the XBase library somehow? As in the library I *really* need to be able to access those arguments and passing through is not an option in all cases.

Currently in XStageRename and XStageConvert the arguments are available as public final variables after they have been parsed in the main method.

To further illustrate why it is not possible to send them as arguments, consider this functional interface (Java 8):

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CleanPathWrappingConsumer extends WrappingConsumer<Path> {
    @Override
    public default void wrappingAccept(final Path path) {
        //need to access global values in XBase
        //from main inject into static from library?
    }

    public void cleanWrappingAccept(final Path path);
}
```

In `wrappingAccept` I need access to `XStageRename.MANUAL_PATH` and likewise `XStageConvert.MANUAL_PATH` and here they cannot be passed.

Comment: *after they have been parsed in the main method* -- if they are known beforehand, then why are they still input on the CLI? Why not just constants? I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Joffrey Because they (directories) may change over time once the application is actually deployed, hence it is not good to keep them constant, as else it would require an unneccessary recompilation of the program.

Comment: Then why not a `static` setter for a `static` variable in XBase? Otherwise, why don't you just pass these arguments on to the library when you instantiate/use it?

Comment: Is your goal, in the end, to remove these common arguments from the CLI of your XStageRename and XStageConvert?

Comment: @Joffrey It could be useful but it's not the main goal. I currently solved it with `XStageRename.MANUAL_PATH = XBase.MANUAL_PATH = Paths.get(args[2])`, which references both the project with arguments and the library.